# How to create the homepage.phtml in Magento 2

Tags: custom, magento2.1.5

How to create create the `custom theme` in **Magento 2**. i have create the custom, in my template i have write the some html code. But its not display default code only display here my codes

> **app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\custom_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="test" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="MainContainerEnclose" htmlId="MainContainerEnclose" />
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

> **app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\Magento_Theme\template\homepage.phtml**

```
<div id="MainContainerEnclose" class="MainContainerEnclose">
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Any one help me

Answer (score 1):

`app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\custom_home.xml`

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <title>Magestore Sample Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
    <media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
    </theme>**strong text**
```

Comment: which file i need to change

Comment: app\design\frontend\accu\accu-theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\custom_home.xml

Comment: i need custom  page and custom page design

Comment: Please refer this link http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-theme-create-sample-custome-theme/ it will help you